# Using Spring WebServiceTemplate with proxy

Tags: web-services, soap, proxy

I have an https soap URL. I want to call this url using WebServiceTemplate throw proxy.

I have added below code for proxy

```
System.setProperty("https.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", <Proxy Host Name>);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", <Proxy Port Number >);
```

and calling

```
TransferDataResponse transferDataResponse = (TransferDataResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(webServiceUrl, transferData);
```

but the call is not routing throw proxy and getting connection refused. Please help to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hasn't been answered and I was stuck on this

I used the below and it worked.

```
Properties systemProps = System.getProperties();
systemProps.put("proxySet", "true");
systemProps.put("proxyHost", "proxyHost");
systemProps.put("proxyPort", "8080");
```

Comment: What is System here? How did u bind Properties to WebServiceTemplate call?